# Mutex with PTHREAD in Windows?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

When a thread terminate its execution calling pthread_exit(NULL), its mutex becomes free or not?

Comment: What mutex would that be?

Comment: What default mutex? In what sense does a thread own a default mutex?

Comment: At the time that the thread exits with pthread_exit, it is the owner of a mutex default .. The question is: when it finishes its execution with the exit, the thread is clear or not the mutex?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`pthread_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_exit.html):

> The pthread_exit() function shall terminate the calling thread and make the value value_ptr available to any successful join with the terminating thread. Any cancellation cleanup handlers that have been pushed and not yet popped shall be popped in the reverse order that they were pushed and then executed. After all cancellation cleanup handlers have been executed, if the thread has any thread-specific data, appropriate destructor functions shall be called in an unspecified order. Thread termination does not release any application visible process resources, including, but not limited to, mutexes and file descriptors, nor does it perform any process-level cleanup actions, including, but not limited to, calling any atexit() routines that may exist.

So no, your mutex will not be released.